# How to efficiently compute WEIGHTED moving average

Tags: matlab, math, mean, weighted

I need to compute a weighted moving average withous loops and withoud storing infromation. The weight could be linear, so that the old sample is weighted less than the new one.

For example, using a 20 samples window, my weights vector would be:

```
[1 2 3 4 5 ... 20]
```

I'm using the following formula to compute the moving mean:

```
   newMean = currMean + (newSample - currMean)/WindowSize
```

now I need to "inject" weight.

What I can know:
1. which sample I'm considering (14th....26th....), I can count.
2. of course, I can know currMean

What I can know but I don't want to do:
1. storing all the samples (in my case they are 1200 x 1980 x 3 matrix, I simply can't store them).

I'm currently using Matlab, but I really do not need the code, just the concept, if it exists.

Thank you.

Comment: I would just use convolution and construct your filter such that all of the weights sum to 1. i.e. `(1:20) ./ sum(1:20)`

Comment: Mmm I'm using very big matrices, I don't think convolution would be good for me. I mean..I'm just using 3 simple math operations right now, why I should introduce convolution only for weights?

Comment: Convolution does *precisely* what you are trying to do and does so very efficiently

Comment: I've access to only a sample at time (I do not remember other samples).

Comment: Yeah but you have to keep the information somewhere, there is no miracle, at least you should keep some information about your last 20 samples !

Comment: Well than I need to store the matrices in a buffer, it's quite a lot of memory, like 1200 x 1980x 3 x WindowSize :S

Comment: Also, I can store the Matrix,bot how I could do the convolution with 3-Dimensional matrix? I've a buffer of 3D matrices.

Comment: You might want to look at (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average) That tells you how to compute an exponentially weighted moving average using no more storage that you do now.

Answer (score 1):

Look into techniques in digital signal processing. You are describing a FIR filter, which can be implemented as a convolution, or as a memory efficient circuit. Basically you can rewrite it as a recursive equation that keeps only the filter-length past filtered intermediate state variables. MATLAB does this in `filter` function (you can chain the internal state to continue filtering). See documentation of `filter` and I also recommend reading a DSP textbook.